# Surprise API - how to load features into Surprise dataset?

Tags: python

For a recommender system, when we are using Surprise, we normally only pass on UserID, ItemID and Rating using load_from_df.

But if I also have other features which I want to load from a df, how can I do it? I couldn't find any useful information or examples on the Surprise API https://surprise.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataset.html.

Can someone guide me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Surprise is a Python scikit for building and analyzing recommender systems that deal with explicit rating data. Surprise was designed with the following purposes in mind: Give users perfect control over their experiments. ... Provide tools to evaluate, analyse and compare the algorithms' performance